# Error "The name transform does not exit in this context."

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am learning UNITY and as process I have written the following code and attached the scrip to the object. But getting the following error.
P.S I am learning programming as well apologies for bad code format.

I tried using both

private/public Transform mover;

and also

private GameObject mover

but still getting error.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ManualMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    Stepmovment mover;
    // location = location + Velocity * Time.Deltatime
    // Velocity  = Velocity + acceleration*Time.Deltatime.
    // transform.position = vector3(locationx, 0, locationy).
    // we will restrict the movement to the topspeed.
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    void Start()
    {
        // Initialize the new mover
        mover = new Stepmovment();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        mover.step();
    }
}
```

```
public class Stepmovment
{
    // basic properties
    Vector3 location, velocity, acceleration;
    float topspeed;

    // Contsructor
    public Stepmovment()
    {
        location = Vector3.zero;
        velocity = Vector3.zero;
        acceleration = new Vector3(0.1f, 0, 0.01f);
        topspeed = 2f;
    }

    public void step()
    {
        if (velocity.magnitude <= topspeed)
        {
            velocity += acceleration * Time.deltaTime;
            velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(velocity, topspeed);
            location += velocity * Time.deltaTime;

            transform.position = new Vector3(location.x, 0, location.z);
        }
        else
        {
            velocity -= acceleration * Time.deltaTime;
            location += velocity * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position = new Vector3(location.x, 0, location.z);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: well `Stepmovment` doesn't have anything called `transform` no ...

Comment: also regarding the `else` case in `step` .. this will most probably go forth and back every frame once the `topspeed` is reached .. you are clamping anyway ... so what is the `else` case good for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error clearly tells you what the problem is.

You are trying to use `transform` variable in the `Stepmovement` class that has no such field.

If you want to change `transform` of your object in the `Stepmovement` class, you need to pass it directly to it.

```cs
public class ManualMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...

    void Start()
    {
        mover = new Stepmovment(transform);
    }

    ...
}

public class Stepmovment
{
    ...

    Transform transform;

    // Contsructor
    public Stepmovment(Transform transformToControl)
    {
        location = Vector3.zero;
        velocity = Vector3.zero;
        acceleration = new Vector3(0.1f, 0, 0.01f);
        topspeed = 2f;
        
        transform = transformToControl;
    }

    ...
}
```